# Unable to install Macbuntu

Tags: macbuntu

I downloaded Macbuntu from http://sourceforge.net/projects/macbuntu/
I extracted it in Downloads folder, and then I dble-clicked "install.sh"(Macbuntu-10.10 folder). When prompted, I clicked RUN IN TERMINAL. Immediately the terminal window appeared on the screen for a second, and disappeared. Nothing happened after that. 
I was trying to follow the instructions posted in this link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/45817/how-to-make-ubuntu-linux-look-like-mac-os-x/

(I am on ubuntu 12.04)

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Macbuntu is for 10.10 and 10.04, **doesn't work in 12.04.**

This is because 10.XX uses Gnome 2, from 11.10 onwards Gnome 3 is used which is incompatible with Gnome 2 theme.

There are Gnome 3 Mac Themes so you can still get the OSX look and feel, but Macbuntu itself won't work unless they update it.

Comment: oh no :( why is that? And what about future releases of Ubuntu? Will i atleast be able to install Macbuntu in future releases? Basically I dont wish to downgrade my Ubuntu version just for this.

Comment: No you won't be able to install this particular theme in the future release as it is extremely unlikely that the future releases will revert back to Gnome 2.

Comment: You may be able to in the future, if macbuntu updates to gnome 3 however.

Answer (score 1):

Adding futher to Uri Herrera's answer, check [this](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/06/mac-os-x-lion-theme-for-ubuntu.html) out. That is for gnome 3 which you could use in ubuntu 12.04.